# Remove double quotes from the strings present inside the arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, double-quotes

I have an array like this:
array = ["apple","orange","pear"]
I want to remove the double quotes from the beginning and end of each one of the strings in the array.
array = [apple,orange,pear]
I tried to loop through each element of the array and did a string replace like the following

```
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i].replace(/"/g, "");
    }
```

But it did not remove the double quotes from the beginning and end of the string.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks much.

Comment: How are you viewing the _Array_ when it has the quotes?

Comment: You're seeing a string literal representation, not the value of the string.

Comment: Not quite understanding ur question ,paul.Can you elaborate a bit ?Its basically a hardcoded array of strings.

Comment: @user2844540: The string values don't actually have quotes.

Comment: When are you seeing the quotes? What are you using to output?

Comment: Notice what Slaks tells you, if you remove the quotes then you will have an array of variables, and if those variables are not defined in your code, you will have an array of errors.

Let´s go back to the beginning, why do you need to remove those quotes? Your answer will allows us to help you.

Answer (score 12):

The only `"`'s I see in your Question are the quotes of the String literals contained in your array.

```
["apple", ...]
 ^     ^
```

You probably aren't aware that

> A string literal is the representation of a string value within the source code of a  computer program.[<sub>(Wikipedia)</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)

and should probably read the MDN article about the [String object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString)

---

If you by accident mean the result of calling `JSON.stringify` on your array.

```
var array = ["apple","orange","pear"];
JSON.stringify (array); //["apple", "orange", "pear"]
```

You can do so by replacing them

```
var string = JSON.stringify(array);
    string.replace (/"/g,''); //"[apple,orange,pear]"
```